# encodeURIComponent() does not work in IE-11-Js/ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to access a url on click of a report using the context history like below:

```
function onClick() {
   let name = encodeURIComponent(title); // title is string- ex: "abc", "test", "user123"
      this.context.history.push({
        pathname: `/report?name="${name}"`
      });
}
```

this works fine in Chrome, FF, but gives 404 on IE.
Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Why not console.log(name) and see what comes out in IE. It seems IE supports encodeURIComponent. Problem might be in use of template literal. Instead of this ``/report?name="${name}"`` try `"/report?name=" + name`

Comment: @ssk: The problem is  IE is not supporting double quotes, when I wrap the name around single quotes, it works fire for IE, but breaks for chrome and FF.